# xcode 6.1 crash after build application succeeded

Tags: ios, xcode6.1

Xcode is crashing without any error after build application succeeded
when I run my app on device.  It does this every time.

I'm using Xcode 6.1 on OS X 10.10.

Comment: I have been using the same configuration. I haven't got any issues as you found it. If you can also try selecting the proper version of iOS device and your xcode settings.